# VBA: Modify chart data range

Tags: excel, vba, charts, range

My "Chart data range" is `='sheet1'!$A$1:$Z$10`. I'd like to make a VBA macro (or if anybody knows a formula I can use, but I couldn't figure one out) to increase the ending column of the range for `chart1` by 1 every time I run the macro. So essentially:

`chart1.endCol = chart1.endCol + 1`

What is the syntax for this using `ActiveChart` or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you want to expand the range (by adding one extra column) to add one more observation for each series in you diagram (and not to add a new series), you could use this code:

```
Sub ChangeChartRange()
    Dim i As Integer, r As Integer, n As Integer, p1 As Integer, p2 As Integer, p3 As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ax As Range

    'Cycles through each series
    For n = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count Step 1
        r = 0

        'Finds the current range of the series and the axis
        For i = 1 To Len(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula) Step 1
            If Mid(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula, i, 1) = "," Then
                r = r + 1
                If r = 1 Then p1 = i + 1
                If r = 2 Then p2 = i
                If r = 3 Then p3 = i
            End If
        Next i


        'Defines new range
        Set rng = Range(Mid(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula, p2 + 1, p3 - p2 - 1))
        Set rng = Range(rng, rng.Offset(0, 1))

        'Sets new range for each series
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Values = rng

        'Updates axis
        Set ax = Range(Mid(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula, p1, p2 - p1))
        Set ax = Range(ax, ax.Offset(0, 1))
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).XValues = ax

    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're going to declare variables (which you should) you should declare them as proper types:  `Dim i as Integer, r as Integer, n as Integer, p1 as Integer, p2 as Integer`.  Your declaration creates `i, r, n, p1` as `Variant` :)

Comment: @DavidZemens I actually wasn't aware of that. Thanks!

Comment: `rng` is assigned twice and I don't think `t` is assigned. Is that a typo?

Comment: And `FullSeriesCollection` is giving an error. And do you know how to adjust the x-axis range?

Comment: @Stuart You are right. That was a typo. See if the code works now. It works for me using Excel 2013.

Comment: You aren't updating the x-axis in each series

Comment: @Stuart It does now :)

Comment: To be even more pedantic about variable types, you should use Long instead of Integer. VBA converts from Integer to Long behind the scenes, processes them as Long, then converts back to Integer. So you get the additional performance hit of variable conversion, and the overflow error occurs after processing is completed and VBA tries to put too large a value into an Integer. Same goes with Double and Single.

Answer (score 7):

`Offset function` dynamic range makes it possible.

**Sample data**

[image]

**Steps**

- Define a dynamic named range
  `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,,,1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$2:$Z$2))` and  give it a
  name `mobileRange`
- Right Click on Chart
- Click on Select Data

This screen will come

[image]

Click on `Edit` under Legend Entries.(mobiles is selected)

[image]

- change the Series value to point to `mobileRange` named range.
- Now if data for future months are added to mobile sales it will automatically reflect in chart.

Comment: I agree this is better for a single data series, but you cannot use this in the "chart data range" for several series. Since I have about a hundred series, I would rather not do this.

Comment: This is a very useful solution. If someone needs to do this with VBA at run-time, check @JonPeltier 's answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60245027/4037170) . Works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you only run the macro with a Chart Selected, my idea is to alter the range in the formula for each Series. You can of cause change to apply to all Charts in a Worksheet.

UPDATE: Have changed code to accommodate multiple series with screenshots

Formatting of new series string needs to include apostrophes around the worksheet name (already changed below): `aFormulaNew(i) = "'" & oRng.Worksheet.Name & "'" & "!" & oRng.Address`. Also, if looking to change rows rather than columns, change the offset to `Set oRng = oRng.Worksheet.Range(oRng, oRng.Offset(1, 0))` or as needed. Can also include `oRng.Offset(1, 0)` for the first element in the range to adjust the start position of the series: `Set oRng = oRng.Worksheet.Range(oRng.Offset(1, 0), oRng.Offset(1, 0))`

```
Sub ChartRangeAdd()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oCht As Chart, aFormulaOld As Variant, aFormulaNew As Variant
    Dim i As Long, s As Long
    Dim oRng As Range, sTmp As String, sBase As String
    
    Set oCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    oCht.Select
    For s = 1 To oCht.SeriesCollection.count
        sTmp = oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula
        sBase = Split(sTmp, "(")(0) & "(<FORMULA>)" ' "=SERIES(" & "<FORMULA>)"
        sTmp = Split(sTmp, "(")(1) ' "..., ..., ...)"
        aFormulaOld = Split(Left(sTmp, Len(sTmp) - 1), ",") ' "..., ..., ..."
        aFormulaNew = Array()
        ReDim aFormulaNew(UBound(aFormulaOld))
        ' Process all series in the formula
        For i = 0 To UBound(aFormulaOld)
            Set oRng = Range(aFormulaOld(i))
            ' Attempt to put the value into Range, keep the same if it's not valid Range
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                Set oRng = oRng.Worksheet.Range(oRng, oRng.Offset(0, 1))
                aFormulaNew(i) = "'" & oRng.Worksheet.Name & "'" & "!" & oRng.Address
            Else
                aFormulaNew(i) = aFormulaOld(i)
                Err.Clear
            End If
        Next i
        sTmp = Replace(sBase, "<FORMULA>", Join(aFormulaNew, ","))
        Debug.Print "Series(" & s & ") from """ & oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula & """ to """ & sTmp & """"
        oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula = sTmp
        sTmp = ""
    Next s
    Set oCht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Sample data - Initial

[image: InitialData]

After first run:

[image: FirstRun]

Second Run:

[image: SecondRun]

Third Run:

[image: ThirdRun]

Comment: The printout seems to be working (using `MsgBox`), but the chart isn't updating.

Comment: @Stuart Code updated to work on first chart in the Activesheet, please post outputs from Immediate window if it doesn't work.

Comment: For some reason @Søren method `Mid` functions did not work for me. @PatricK option using `Split` saved me.

Answer (score 1):

PatricK's answer works great with some minor adjustments:

Formatting of new series string needs to include apostrophes around the worksheet name on line 22  `aFormulaNew(i) = "'" & oRng.Worksheet.Name & "'" & "!" & oRng.Address`. Also, if looking to change rows rather than columns, change the offset on line 21 to `Set oRng = oRng.Worksheet.Range(oRng, oRng.Offset(1, 0))` or as needed. Can also include `oRng.Offset(1, 0)` for the first element in the range to adjust the start position of the series: `Set oRng = oRng.Worksheet.Range(oRng.Offset(1, 0), oRng.Offset(1, 0))`

```
Sub ChartRangeAdd()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oCht As Chart, aFormulaOld As Variant, aFormulaNew As Variant
    Dim i As Long, s As Long
    Dim oRng As Range, sTmp As String, sBase As String

    Set oCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    oCht.Select
    For s = 1 To oCht.SeriesCollection.count
        sTmp = oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula
        sBase = Split(sTmp, "(")(0) & "(<FORMULA>)" ' "=SERIES(" & "<FORMULA>)"
        sTmp = Split(sTmp, "(")(1) ' "..., ..., ...)"
        aFormulaOld = Split(Left(sTmp, Len(sTmp) - 1), ",") ' "..., ..., ..."
        aFormulaNew = Array()
        ReDim aFormulaNew(UBound(aFormulaOld))
        ' Process all series in the formula
        For i = 0 To UBound(aFormulaOld)
            Set oRng = Range(aFormulaOld(i))
            ' Attempt to put the value into Range, keep the same if it's not valid Range
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                Set oRng = oRng.Worksheet.Range(oRng, oRng.Offset(0, 1))
                aFormulaNew(i) = "'" & oRng.Worksheet.Name & "'" & "!" & oRng.Address
            Else
                aFormulaNew(i) = aFormulaOld(i)
                Err.Clear
            End If
        Next i
        sTmp = Replace(sBase, "<FORMULA>", Join(aFormulaNew, ","))
        Debug.Print "Series(" & s & ") from """ & oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula & """ to """ & sTmp & """"
        oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula = sTmp
        sTmp = ""
    Next s
    Set oCht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

PatricK and sirbedevire got me started with this fairly well. Now, I'm trying to consolidate it into a separate sub I can reference to process multiple charts. Unfortunately, I'm missing something in the referencing so it's not making the updates (and not producing an error).

1st sub using 2nd sub

```
If ws < numTabs - 1 Then
    chartUpdate Summary, Chart_BidsByMonth ' Name of sheet with target chart, Name of target chart
    chartUpdate Summary, Chart_SoldByMonth ' Name of sheet with target chart, Name of target chart
End If
```

2nd sub processing chart range update

```
Sub chartUpdate(shtRef As Variant, chtRef As Variant)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oCht As Chart, aFormulaOld As Variant, aFormulaNew As Variant
    Dim n As Long, s As Long
    Dim oRng As Range, sTmp As String, sBase As String

        ' Update chart referenced as chtRef '
        Set oCht = Sheets(""" & shtRef & """).ChartObjects(""" & chtRef """).Chart
        oCht.Select
        For s = 1 To oCht.SeriesCollection.Count
            sTmp = oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula
            sBase = Split(sTmp, "(")(0) & "(<FORMULA>)" ' "=SERIES(" & "<FORMULA>)"
            sTmp = Split(sTmp, "(")(1) ' "..., ..., ...)"
            aFormulaOld = Split(Left(sTmp, Len(sTmp) - 1), ",") ' "..., ..., ..."
            aFormulaNew = Array()
            ReDim aFormulaNew(UBound(aFormulaOld))
            ' Process all series in the formula
            For n = 0 To UBound(aFormulaOld)
                Set oRng = Range(aFormulaOld(n))
                ' Attempt to put the value into Range, keep the same if it's not valid Range
                If Err.Number = 0 Then
                    Set oRng = oRng.Worksheet.Range(oRng, oRng.Offset(0, 1))
                    aFormulaNew(n) = "'" & oRng.Worksheet.Name & "'" & "!" & oRng.Address
                Else
                    aFormulaNew(n) = aFormulaOld(i)
                    Err.Clear
                End If
            Next n
            sTmp = Replace(sBase, "<FORMULA>", Join(aFormulaNew, ","))
            Debug.Print "Series(" & s & ") from """ & oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula & """ to """ & sTmp & """"
            oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula = sTmp
            sTmp = ""
        Next s
        Set oCht = Nothing
        ' End charts update '
    End Sub
```