# VBA: Reducing chart data range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to modify the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19286721/119775) so that instead of increasing the range by one, it reduces reduces the range by one.  Any ideas on how to do this?

```
Sub ChangeChartRange()

Dim i As Integer, r As Integer, n As Integer, p1 As Integer, p2 As Integer, p3 As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim ax As Range

'Cycles through each series
For n = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count Step 1
    r = 0

    'Finds the current range of the series and the axis
    For i = 1 To Len(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula) Step 1
        If Mid(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula, i, 1) = "," Then
            r = r + 1
            If r = 1 Then p1 = i + 1
            If r = 2 Then p2 = i
            If r = 3 Then p3 = i
        End If
    Next i


    'Defines new range
    Set rng = Range(Mid(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula, p2 + 1, p3 - p2 - 1))
    Set rng = Range(rng, rng.Offset(0, 1))

    'Sets new range for each series
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Values = rng

    'Updates axis
    Set ax = Range(Mid(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula, p1, p2 - p1))
    Set ax = Range(ax, ax.Offset(0, 1))
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).XValues = ax

Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Use John Walkenbachs [class module](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_class_module_to_manipulate_a_chart_series/) approach. The code above failed on my chart type.

Comment: You just reposted the code from that other answer... Have you actually tried anything? e.g. try to understand what it does, and have a go at modifying it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I made effort to modify the code to reduce the range by 1 column.  I'll be more specific in documenting same in the future.  Lesson learned.  The original coder provided the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced two lines in the original code in order to reduce the number of columns in a chart each time the macro runs.

```
Sub ChangeChartRange()
    Dim i As Integer, r As Integer, n As Integer, p1 As Integer, p2 As Integer, p3 As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ax As Range

    'Cycles through each series
    For n = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count Step 1
        r = 0

        'Finds the current range of the series and the axis
        For i = 1 To Len(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula) Step 1
            If Mid(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula, i, 1) = "," Then
                r = r + 1
                If r = 1 Then p1 = i + 1
                If r = 2 Then p2 = i
                If r = 3 Then p3 = i
            End If
        Next i

        'Defines new range
        Set rng = Range(Mid(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula, p2 + 1, p3 - p2 - 1))
        Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count - 1) '~~> Replaced line

        'Sets new range for each series
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Values = rng

        'Updates axis
        Set ax = Range(Mid(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula, p1, p2 - p1))
        Set ax = ax.Resize(ax.Rows.Count, ax.Columns.Count - 1)     '~~> Replaced line
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).XValues = ax

    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: Soren, I tried the code and it worked perfectly. I'm going to expand its use to 40+ excel charts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is change

`Set rng = Range(rng, rng.Offset(0, 1))`

to

`Set rng = Range(rng, rng.Offset(0, -1))`.

**EDIT :** Try changing this equation around

`Set rng = Range(Mid(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula, p2 + 1, p3 - p2 - 1))`

For example, you could try :

`Set rng = Range(Mid(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula, p2 - 1, p3 - p2 - 1))`

or

`Set rng = Range(Mid(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula, p2 + 1, p3 + p2 - 1))`

or

`Set rng = Range(Mid(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Formula, p2 + 1, p3 - p2 + 1))`

And so on so forth...

Comment: Thanks Bernard.  I tried your recommendation but it didn't work.  Though it seems it should.  Continuing to work it.  Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free add-in on my site to adjust the chart series formula. It works like Find-Replace. Read the last row of data from the series formula, that's the change-from value, subtract one to get the change-to value. The tutorial is [Change Series Formula – Improved Routines](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/change-series-formula-improved-routines/), and it starts with some VBA code if you want to try it yourself, but near the end is a link to the "Change Series Formula" add-in.