# Scroll through data series in excel to create a pseudo-animation

Tags: excel

I have data formatted like this in excel (in colummns)

```
x    y1    y2    y3    ...  yn
```

What I want to do is create a scatter plot plotting one y data series at a time against the same x series each time. I want to then be able to scroll through each y data series, from y1 to yn, always displaying one data series at a time on the same chart, to show a sort of time progression of how y evolves.

To explain it a different way, I want to start off with y1 plotted against x. I then scroll one increment to the right, and now y2 is plotted against x on that same chart. Scroll again, y3 is plotted, so on and so forth.

I know you can implement a scroll bar in Excel, that seems easy enough. What I'm not sure about is if it can manipulate data series and charts in the way that I want.

Is this possible?

Comment: yes. what have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, maybe I wasn't using good search terms, but when I googled it, all the info was about scrolling through one data series, when you couldn't fit the entire range in x values comfortably on one chart. There was no mention, at least that I found, about scrolling through data series themselves. If you could point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated

Comment: you can set up dynamic data range, e.g. inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/a/19287244/1176601, and then change it to next/previous column with 2 buttons..

Comment: I created a dynamic range using the formula `=OFFSET(INDIRECT("B"&(Sheet1!$P$2)),0,0,1,COUNT(Sheet2!$B$2:$CJD$2))` and saved it under the name 'rho'. The cell P2 contains the value set my the slider, and I transposed my data so that it would be appropriate to scroll through rows instead of columns. However when I follow the instructions in  stackoverflow.com/a/19287244/1176601, and enter in the name of my dynamic range for the "Series values" I get a message saying "The formula you typed contains an error"

Comment: I just needed to change the formula to `=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Sheet2!B"&(Sheet1!$P$2)),0,0,1,COUNT(Sheet2!$B$2:$CJD$2))