# VBA to update charts on another tab

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with a large data set on one tab for multiple inductors and about 30 charts on another tab based on the data.

I've found the below post

[VBA: Modify chart data range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285577/vba-modify-chart-data-range)

And the below code which is great:

```
Sub ChartRangeAdd()
On Error Resume Next
Dim oCht As Chart, aFormulaOld As Variant, aFormulaNew As Variant
Dim i As Long, s As Long
Dim oRng As Range, sTmp As String, sBase As String

Set oCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
oCht.Select
For s = 1 To oCht.SeriesCollection.count
    sTmp = oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula
    sBase = Split(sTmp, "(")(0) & "(<FORMULA>)" ' "=SERIES(" & "<FORMULA>)"
    sTmp = Split(sTmp, "(")(1) ' "..., ..., ...)"
    aFormulaOld = Split(Left(sTmp, Len(sTmp) - 1), ",") ' "..., ..., ..."
    aFormulaNew = Array()
    ReDim aFormulaNew(UBound(aFormulaOld))
    ' Process all series in the formula
    For i = 0 To UBound(aFormulaOld)
        Set oRng = Range(aFormulaOld(i))
        ' Attempt to put the value into Range, keep the same if it's not valid Range
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Set oRng = oRng.Worksheet.Range(oRng, oRng.Offset(0, 1))
            aFormulaNew(i) = oRng.Worksheet.Name & "!" & oRng.Address
        Else
            aFormulaNew(i) = aFormulaOld(i)
            Err.Clear
        End If
    Next i
    sTmp = Replace(sBase, "<FORMULA>", Join(aFormulaNew, ","))
    Debug.Print "Series(" & s & ") from """ & oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula & """ to """ & sTmp & """"
    oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula = sTmp
    sTmp = ""
Next s
Set oCht = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm at bit of novice with VBA, but could any one else help me modify the above to update multiple charts instead of only one and in another tab please to the data?

Comment: An alternative to trying to change the data range for all your charts would be to point all the charts at a constant data range and change the contents of that data range instead.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I'll explain a little bit more, at the moment I have months running A1 to AB1 for example and then below a range of data for different things, the charts plot the values recorded for each month, but it's a pain to update so many charts manually just because I've added another new month, the code above is great but it just needs a slight mod to update all the charts I have, when I've tried to add extra subs I just get an error, admittedly I'm not very familiar with the syntax, could you help please?

Comment: I was just suggesting that you point your graphs at, for example, column AZ and put formulae in AZ that picks up values from the correct column depending on which month you pick. This approach makes it easier to cater for the addition of new charts without having to modify any VBA.

Answer (score 0):

To reference a worksheet by its name you use the syntax:

```
Worksheets("sheet_name")
```

If you want to use a worksheet variable so you can easily refer to the same worksheet several times in your code, use:

```
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Set mySheet = Worksheets("sheet_name")

mySheet.Range("A1").Value = "some thing"
```

Each worksheet has a `ChartObjects` collection over which you can iterate.

```
Dim cht As ChartObject

For Each cht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet_name").ChartObjects
    Debug.Print cht.Name
Next cht
```

Bearing these points in mind, your code block should get changed to (Warning - this is untested):

```
For Each oCht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet_name").ChartObjects
    For s = 1 To oCht.SeriesCollection.count
        sTmp = oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula
        sBase = Split(sTmp, "(")(0) & "(<FORMULA>)" ' "=SERIES(" & "<FORMULA>)"
        sTmp = Split(sTmp, "(")(1) ' "..., ..., ...)"
        aFormulaOld = Split(Left(sTmp, Len(sTmp) - 1), ",") ' "..., ..., ..."
        aFormulaNew = Array()
        ReDim aFormulaNew(UBound(aFormulaOld))
        ' Process all series in the formula
        For i = 0 To UBound(aFormulaOld)
            Set oRng = Range(aFormulaOld(i))
            ' Attempt to put the value into Range, keep the same if it's not valid Range
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                Set oRng = oRng.Worksheet.Range(oRng, oRng.Offset(0, 1))
                aFormulaNew(i) = oRng.Worksheet.Name & "!" & oRng.Address
            Else
                aFormulaNew(i) = aFormulaOld(i)
                Err.Clear
            End If
        Next i
        sTmp = Replace(sBase, "<FORMULA>", Join(aFormulaNew, ","))
        Debug.Print "Series(" & s & ") from """ & oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula & """ to """ & sTmp & """"
        oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula = sTmp
        sTmp = ""
    Next s
Next oCht
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was just being being stupid, I made a far simpler fix after all that. I just ended up adding a single extra line to loop over the chart numbers, 1 to x.

Comment: The abbove code currently also extends the range of the series name reference, which is annoying, the names of the series should be static, how can I stop it moving along this row too on every run?