# VBA: Update chart to last three periods of data

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have several charts in a workbook (one per worksheet) that report the last three weeks of data. The source data is non-contiguous columns in a ListObject table. Every week when the tables are updated with a new week of data (additional row) I want the charts to update.

This is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285577/vba-modify-chart-data-range) but I'm updating the series range instead of adding another series.

Here's some sample data:

```
A       B       C       D       E       F
Start   End     Green   Yellow  Red     Total
------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
1/1/16  1/7/16  10      10      10      30
1/8/16  1/14/16 12      12      12      36
1/15/16 1/21/16 12      20      18      50
1/22/16 1/28/16 30      10      50      45
```

The chart would first look like this:
[image: Chart prior to VBA modification.]

Afterwards it would like like this: (disregard color difference)
[image: Chart after VBA modification]

Any suggestions on the easiest way to do this?

The Series formulas end up looking like this:

```
=SERIES(Project!$A$2,Project!$C$1:$E$1,Project!$C$2:$E$2,1)
=SERIES(Project!$A$3,Project!$C$1:$E$1,Project!$C$3:$E$3,2)
=SERIES(Project!$A$4,Project!$C$1:$E$1,Project!$C$4:$E$4,3)
```

I'm thinking of iterating through each Series in SeriesCollection, parsing out the different comma separated values, and updating the range. Something like this:

```
set clnSeries = activechart.seriescollection 
dim strSeriesTemp as string 'Placeholder for previous series formula
For i = clnSeries.count to 1 step -1
  if strSeriesTemp = "" then
    strSeriesTemp = clnSeries(i).formula
    arrSeries = split(clnSeries(i).formula, ",")
    for i = lbound(arrSeries) to ubound(arrSeries)
      select case i
        'Move legend label one row down
        case 1: strFormula = arrSeries(i).offset(1,0).address
        'Leave series labels the same
        case 2: strFormula = strFormula & arrSeries(i)
        'Move series values one row down
        case 3: strFormula = strFormula & arrSeries(i).offset(1,0).address
        'Set series index
        case 4: strFormula = strFormula & i
      end select
      strFormula = "=SERIES(" & strFormula & ")"
  else
    clnSeries(i).formula = strFormula
  end if
next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to approach this problem is with dynamic named ranges.

Create the following three named ranges in the Name Manager under the Formulas tab:

```
Ultimate=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$B:$B),Sheet1!$B:$B,0)-1,2,1,3)
Penultimate=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$B:$B),Sheet1!$B:$B,0)-2,2,1,3)
Antepenultimate=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$B:$B),Sheet1!$B:$B,0)-3,2,1,3)
```

[image: Define Dynamic Ranges]

Then right click on the chart, Select Data, Edit the Series values to be:

```
=Sheet1!Antepenultimate
=Sheet1!Penultimate
=Sheet1!Ultimate
```

Then every time you add a new row to your columns, these three ranges will automatically update to be the last three rows assuming the inputs are in chronological order. (Note that `Sheet1` will update to your workbook name if you go back to look at it since it's a workbook level named range.)

Explanation: The `OFFSET` formula references cell A1, then looks down column B until it finds the latest date and shifts down by the latest date's row number, backs up the necessary number of rows, shifts to the right two columns, and finally selects a 1x3 range.

[image: Enter Series Values]

Note: In order for your series names to update properly as well, you'll need to make named ranges for them as well.

Hint:

```
UltimateName=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,MATCH(MAX(Sheet1!$B:$B),Sheet1!$B:$B,0)-1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexis, this is helpful. I'm using ListObject tables, and each sheet has data that exists below the respective tables so seeking a max value of an entire column is impractical for me. I'm trying to modify your code to select the max value from the table. Another challenge is that I have about 10 sheets where this needs to be done so I effectively have to create about 30 named ranges, but so far this seems easier than writing VBA code.

Comment: You should just be able to replace $B:$B with whatever your limited range you'd like to search from is.

Comment: My formulas are looking more complicated:
    =OFFSET(tblMCC,MATCH(MAX(tblMCC[Start]),tblMCC[Start],1)-3,MATCH("Green",tblMCC[#Headers],0),3,1)

And when I try to create the Named range in VBA it keeps getting rejected.