# VBA Chart range substract

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, charts

I found this code, which add's one extra column to the chart each time it runs.
Meaning first time it runs it shows week 1-7, secound time 1-8, next 1-9 and I would like it to show 2-7, 3-8, 4-9 ect.

```
Sub ChartRangeAdd()
On Error Resume Next
Dim oCht As Chart, aFormulaOld As Variant, aFormulaNew As Variant
Dim i As Long, s As Long
    Dim oRng As Range, sTmp As String, sBase As String

Set oCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
oCht.Select
For s = 1 To oCht.SeriesCollection.count
    sTmp = oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula
    sBase = Split(sTmp, "(")(0) & "(<FORMULA>)" ' "=SERIES(" & "<FORMULA>)"
    sTmp = Split(sTmp, "(")(1) ' "..., ..., ...)"
    aFormulaOld = Split(Left(sTmp, Len(sTmp) - 1), ",") ' "..., ..., ..."
    aFormulaNew = Array()
    ReDim aFormulaNew(UBound(aFormulaOld))
    ' Process all series in the formula
    For i = 0 To UBound(aFormulaOld)
        Set oRng = Range(aFormulaOld(i))
        ' Attempt to put the value into Range, keep the same if it's not valid Range
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Set oRng = oRng.Worksheet.Range(oRng, oRng.Offset(0, 1))
            aFormulaNew(i) = oRng.Worksheet.Name & "!" & oRng.Address
        Else
            aFormulaNew(i) = aFormulaOld(i)
            Err.Clear
        End If
    Next i
    sTmp = Replace(sBase, "<FORMULA>", Join(aFormulaNew, ","))
    Debug.Print "Series(" & s & ") from """ & oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula & """ to """ & sTmp & """"
    oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula = sTmp
    sTmp = ""
Next s
Set oCht = Nothing
End Sub
```

I want to do the opposite of this code, so instead of adding a column one column should be substracted. How can the code be modifued to do this?

(LINK: [VBA: Modify chart data range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285577/vba-modify-chart-data-range/19287326#19287326))

Thank you!

Comment: `For s = oCht.SeriesCollection.count-5 To oCht.SeriesCollection.count`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I cant get it to work with you code. 

Regards

Comment: did it not work at all or just not as you requested?

Comment: It did not work at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the line

```
Set oRng = oRng.Worksheet.Range(oRng, oRng.Offset(0, 1))
```

to

```
Set oRng = oRng.Worksheet.Range(oRng.Offset(0, 1), oRng.Offset(0, 1))
```