# Update Chart to include last row data using defined range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question , similar to this [VBA: Modify chart data range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285577/vba-modify-chart-data-range)
But I the answer was based on horizontal data set.

How can I make this named range update to include latest row on a vertical column set ?

This is what I got as my formula, B1 being the header, and Column B will have all my data.

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,,,1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B2:$B))`

**Edit**

I am using the following defined range now:

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B2:$B1000),1)`

but when I add it to my chart I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there - you basically need to swap height parameter with width:
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B1:$B1000),1)

Here's a range that excludes header in B1:
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B2:$B1000),1)

Of course you're welcome to extend the B1:B1000 range.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I cannot add this named range to my chart. I am getting error . I'll add it to question.

Comment: I see. This must be happening because of lack of absolute references in Named Range formula. Once you start selecting other cells / playing around with the chart, the range will change (i.e. shift to your current selection) and thus it will stop working properly. Try adding absolute references to all cells: =OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000),1)

Comment: Could you let me know what is the result of your COUNTA formula? =COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000)
   Another check might be to go to your Name Manager, select your Name and then select inside of the "Refers to" window - it should highlight the range which is represented by this formula.

Comment: Interesting, when I enter in the formula ,`=COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$1000)` the open file dialog comes up. then I click cancel and its a value of 1.. btw my sheet name isnt actually Sheet1.

Comment: Thanks for checking - this might be the issue. Try updating the whole formula and replace Sheet1 with your sheet name, for example: =OFFSET('My Sheet'!$B$2,,,COUNTA('My Sheet'!$B$2:$B$1000),1)
   Then repeat the checks we just discussed (check the result of COUNTA formula and check the range that is selected in Name Manager > Refers To)

Comment: Oaky seems to be working now.. it works for one of my column. I am trying on another column on another sheet, now the data doesnt fill all the way to last row. But the first one worked nicely. `=OFFSET('Risk'!$J$2,,,COUNTA('Risk'!$J$2:$J$1000),1)` only goes to row 307?

Comment: Glad it worked for the first one! =COUNTA counts the number of cells in a range that are not empty. Is it possible that you have some blanks in column J? For example, if you have data in cells J2:J302, then 98 empty rows and then another set of values in J400:J406, COUNTA will return =307, and that's where your OFFSET function is going to stop.

Comment: That's good! It means our original formula is still working :) now you either remove those blanks, or you need to use MATCH formula to find the last number in a given column (assuming you are using numbers). Simply use: =MATCH(10^308,Risk!$J:$J,1)
   If it gives you a correct value (row number of the last row with a number), then you need to modify your Named Range to use the following:
=OFFSET(Risk!$J$2,,,MATCH(10^308,Risk!$J$2:$J$1000,1),1)

Comment: why do you use `10^308` ? I want to reuse this formula so I don't want to explicitly name blanks. Is there a way to do this without explicitly saying how much blanks there are?

Comment: 10^308 is the biggest number you can have in a single Excel cell. If you are trying to MATCH this number, it will always find the latest row number in a given range. Let me know if it works for you - it should ignore blanks and give you the correct row number (unless you are having text values in column J).

Comment: Thanks you have been very helpful! I wish I was you.